# WPF: Datagrid - Apply DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am quite new to WPF (from Winforms). I am using .Net 4.5 and the default DataGrid that comes along with the framework in WPF. The columns are created dynamically because I do not know at compile time. Now, based on data some columns will be read-only and some will be of ComboBox type.

- How can I apply [this logic dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) while creating the columns dynamically as shown below. here is the code which I wrote so far. Whenever the data changes, the columns are generated dynamically based on the data.
- Also, how do I generate "different types" of column dynamically (ComboBox, TextBox, etc...) based on data. The *MVVM-ish way* in WPF is kind of restricting me because I do not have much knowledge about templating. I am sure it should be easy once I get through.

NB: Currently all this is working fine. I have a read-only databound grid. But, there is no support for selective editable columns and selective ComboBox columns.

```
public class DatagridExtension {
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RefDataSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "RefDataSource",
            typeof(RefDataRecord),
            typeof(DatagridExtension),
            new PropertyMetadata( default(RefDataRecord), OnRefDataSourceChanged)
        );


    private static void OnRefDataSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = d as DataGrid;
        var dataSource = e.NewValue as RefDataRecord;

        grid.ItemsSource = dataSource;
        grid.Columns.Clear();
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var col in dataSource.Columns)
        {
            grid.Columns.Add(
                new DataGridTextColumn
                    {
                        Header = col.Name,
                        Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", count))
                    }
                );
            count++;
        }
    }

    public static RefDataRecord GetRefDataSource(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return (RefDataRecord) dependencyObject.GetValue(RefDataSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRefDataSource(DependencyObject dependencyObject, RefDataRecord value)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(RefDataSourceProperty, value);
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct answer - http://www.paulstovell.com/dynamic-datagrid (see the template creation logic dynamically. Its clever).

And, MMVM will  be achieved like this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36462/Binding-a-ListView-to-a-Data-Matrix (almost what I have posted in the question)

Answer (score 2):

WPF DataGrid creates [DataGridComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx) by default if data source property type derives from [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx) and sets [DataGridColumn.IsReadyOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.isreadonly.aspx) by default if property doesn't have public setter or if property has [ReadOnlyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.readonlyattribute.aspx) with [ReadOnlyAttribute.IsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.readonlyattribute.isreadonly.aspx) = true.

I will now show how to customize DataGrid column generation if your data source properties do not satisfy default conditions stated above.

Firstly, I will introduce two attributes used to specify that property is read-only (EditableAttribute) and that property should be visualized as ComboBox with predefined drop-down items (NameValueAttribute).

Here is **EditableAttribute.cs**:

```
using System;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class EditableAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public bool AllowEdit { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is **NameValueAttribute.cs**:

```
using System;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public sealed class NameValueAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Next, we need some sample classes that will be used for demonstration.

So here is **Person.cs** class that will represent a single item (row) in a DataGrid:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public class Person : ObservableObject
    {
        private string name;
        private string surname;
        private char gender;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set { this.SetValue(ref this.name, value, "Name"); }
        }

        [Editable(AllowEdit = false)]
        public string Surname
        {
            get { return this.surname; }
            set { this.SetValue(ref this.surname, value, "Surname"); }
        }

        [NameValue(Name = "Male", Value = 'M')]
        [NameValue(Name = "Female", Value = 'F')]
        public char Gender
        {
            get { return this.gender; }
            set { this.SetValue(ref this.gender, value, "Gender"); }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how Surname property has EditableAttribute applied and Gender property has NameValueAttributes applied.

And here is **People.cs** class that will represent DataGrid's data source:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public class People : ObservableCollection<Person>
    {
        public People()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
                this.Items.Add(new Person()
                {
                    Name = "Name " + i,
                    Surname = "Surname " + i,
                    Gender = i % 2 == 0 ? 'M' : 'F'
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Base class for Person is **ObservableObject.cs** which is common to all data-binding applications:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        protected void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                field = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here is a XAML for **MainWindow.xaml** that hosts DataGrid control:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:People x:Key="itemsSource"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource itemsSource}" AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"/>
</Window>
```

Crucial part is [DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn.aspx) event handler `OnAutoGeneratingColumn`.
This event gets fired after DataGrid generates a DataGridColumn and is fired once for every auto-generated column. It is used to customize the auto-generated column or specify different one, depending on the [provided data source property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridautogeneratingcolumneventargs.propertydescriptor.aspx).

Here is **MainWindow.xaml.cs** code-behind in which `OnAutoGeneratingColumn` event handler does exactly that. It customized generated column by setting it as read-only if data source property has EditableAttribute with AllowEdit = false, and it overrides auto-generated column with DataGridComboBoxColumn if data source property has NameValueAttributes:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            var propertyDescriptor = (PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor;
            var dataBoundColumn = (DataGridBoundColumn)e.Column;

            var comboBoxColumn = GenerateComboBoxColumn(propertyDescriptor, dataBoundColumn);
            if (comboBoxColumn != null)
                e.Column = comboBoxColumn;

            if (IsReadOnlyProperty(propertyDescriptor))
                e.Column.IsReadOnly = true;
        }

        private static DataGridComboBoxColumn GenerateComboBoxColumn(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, DataGridBoundColumn dataBoundColumn)
        {
            var nameValueAttributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(propertyDescriptor.ComponentType.GetProperty(propertyDescriptor.Name)).OfType<NameValueAttribute>().ToArray();

            if (nameValueAttributes.Length > 0)
                return new DataGridComboBoxColumn()
                {
                    ItemsSource = nameValueAttributes,
                    DisplayMemberPath = "Name",
                    SelectedValuePath = "Value",
                    SelectedValueBinding = dataBoundColumn.Binding
                };
            else
                return null;
        }

        private static bool IsReadOnlyProperty(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
        {
            var editableAttribute = propertyDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<EditableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            return editableAttribute != null ? !editableAttribute.AllowEdit : false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE FOR DYNAMIC CASE:**

WPF supports dynamic reflection with [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) implemented on data items and [ITypedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist.aspx) implemented on collection.
Also, .NET 4.5 supports [ICustomTypeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.icustomtypeprovider.aspx), but since I do not have .NET 4.5 installed, I haven't tested it.

**NameValueAttribute.cs** is same as before.

Here is very simple implementation of ICustomTypeDescriptor and ITypedList in a working sample:

**DataProperty.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public class DataProperty : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        private readonly Type propertyType;
        private readonly bool isReadOnly;
        private readonly Attribute[] attributes;

        public DataProperty(string propertyName, Type propertyType, bool isReadOnly, params Attribute[] attributes)
            : base(propertyName, null)
        {
            this.propertyType = propertyType;
            this.isReadOnly = isReadOnly;
            this.attributes = attributes;
        }

        protected override Attribute[] AttributeArray
        {
            get { return this.attributes; }
            set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override Type ComponentType
        {
            get { return typeof(DataRecord); }
        }

        public override Type PropertyType
        {
            get { return this.propertyType; }
        }

        public override bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return this.isReadOnly; }
        }

        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            return ((DataRecord)component)[this.Name];
        }

        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            if (!this.isReadOnly)
                ((DataRecord)component)[this.Name] = value;
        }

        #region Not implemented PropertyDescriptor Members

        public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**DataRecord.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public class DataRecord : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICustomTypeDescriptor
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        internal ITypedList container;

        private readonly IDictionary<string, object> values = new SortedList<string, object>();

        public object this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                object value;
                this.values.TryGetValue(propertyName, out value);
                return value;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!object.Equals(this[propertyName], value))
                {
                    this.values[propertyName] = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
        {
            return this.container.GetItemProperties(null);
        }

        #region Not implemented ICustomTypeDescriptor Members

        AttributeCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetClassName()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetComponentName()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        TypeConverter ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        EventDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        PropertyDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**DataRecordCollection.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public class DataRecordCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ITypedList where T : DataRecord
    {
        private readonly PropertyDescriptorCollection properties;

        public DataRecordCollection(params DataProperty[] properties)
        {
            this.properties = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties);
        }

        protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
        {
            item.container = this;
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
        }

        PropertyDescriptorCollection ITypedList.GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            return this.properties;
        }

        string ITypedList.GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"/>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var records = new DataRecordCollection<DataRecord>(
                new DataProperty("Name", typeof(string), false),
                new DataProperty("Surname", typeof(string), true),
                new DataProperty("Gender", typeof(char), false, new NameValueAttribute() { Name = "Male", Value = 'M' }, new NameValueAttribute() { Name = "Female", Value = 'F' }));

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                var record = new DataRecord();
                record["Name"] = "Name " + i;
                record["Surname"] = "Surname " + i;
                record["Gender"] = i % 2 == 0 ? 'M' : 'F';
                records.Add(record);
            }

            this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = records;
        }

        private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Column.Header = ((PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor).DisplayName;

            var propertyDescriptor = (PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor;
            var dataBoundColumn = (DataGridBoundColumn)e.Column;

            var comboBoxColumn = GenerateComboBoxColumn(propertyDescriptor, dataBoundColumn);
            if (comboBoxColumn != null)
                e.Column = comboBoxColumn;
        }

        private static DataGridComboBoxColumn GenerateComboBoxColumn(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, DataGridBoundColumn dataBoundColumn)
        {
            var nameValueAttributes = propertyDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<NameValueAttribute>().ToArray();

            if (nameValueAttributes.Length > 0)
                return new DataGridComboBoxColumn()
                {
                    ItemsSource = nameValueAttributes,
                    DisplayMemberPath = "Name",
                    SelectedValuePath = "Value",
                    SelectedValueBinding = dataBoundColumn.Binding
                };
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stipo, Thanks for replying. In my case I do not know the columns at compile - time. The way you have represented using the Person object, think I have just a property bag of generic System.Object So, I cannot set the attributes the way you have shown.

Comment: No, it won't work for AutogenerateColumns = false because then you must create columns by yourself. The whole point of ITypedList is to provide all the necessary information to DataGrid so it automatically generates columns from information provided by ITypedList.

Comment: I have really learned something new. The `PropertyDescriptor` mechanism is so much exciting. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, one of the main advantages of WPF to WinForms is ability to declare user interface using templates. And **you should avoid declaring UI components in code as as possible**.

As i understand you want to display collection of different objects based on object type/data.
The best way to implement such logic  - implement your own [TemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.selecttemplate.aspx)

I suggest you read next articles:

1. http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html
2. http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

P.S.
For reference. Example of declaring DataTemplate in code:

```
//create the data template
DataTemplate cardLayout = new DataTemplate();
cardLayout.DataType = typeof(CreditCardPayment);

//set up the stack panel
FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
spFactory.Name = "myComboFactory";
spFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

//set up the card holder textblock
FrameworkElementFactory cardHolder = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
cardHolder.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("BillToName"));
cardHolder.SetValue(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, "Card Holder Name");
spFactory.AppendChild(cardHolder);

//set up the card number textblock
FrameworkElementFactory cardNumber = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
cardNumber.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("SafeNumber"));
cardNumber.SetValue(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, "Credit Card Number");
spFactory.AppendChild(cardNumber);

//set up the notes textblock
FrameworkElementFactory notes = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
notes.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Notes"));
notes.SetValue(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, "Notes");
spFactory.AppendChild(notes);

//set the visual tree of the data template
cardLayout.VisualTree = spFactory;

//set the item template to be our shiny new data template
drpCreditCardNumberWpf.ItemTemplate = cardLayout;
```

but as i say above, you should avoid this.

Comment: You are only contradicting your solution and asking me to avoid this. So, I will wait for better answers then.

Answer (score 1):

I was away from the Internet for a few days, but I think that I have found the better approach with simplified PropertyDescriptor architecture which doesn't require to implement ICustomTypeDescriptor. Here is the entire code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var records = new RecordCollection(new Property("Name"), new Property("Surname"));

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
                records.Add(new Record()
                {
                    { "Name", "John " + i },
                    { "Surname", "Doe " + i }
                });

            this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = records;
        }

        private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            var property = e.PropertyDescriptor as Property;
            if (property != null)
            {
                var binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath(property), Mode = property.IsReadOnly ? BindingMode.OneWay : BindingMode.TwoWay };
                var dataGridBoundColumn = e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
                if (dataGridBoundColumn != null)
                    dataGridBoundColumn.Binding = binding;
                else
                {
                    var dataGridComboBoxColumn = e.Column as DataGridComboBoxColumn;
                    if (dataGridComboBoxColumn != null)
                        dataGridComboBoxColumn.SelectedItemBinding = binding;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class Record : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEnumerable
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private readonly IDictionary<string, object> values = new SortedList<string, object>(StringComparer.Ordinal);

        private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        public object GetValue(string name)
        {
            object value;
            return this.values.TryGetValue(name, out value) ? value : null;
        }

        public void SetValue(string name, object value)
        {
            if (!object.Equals(this.GetValue(name), value))
            {
                this.values[name] = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public void Add(string name, object value)
        {
            this.values[name] = value;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.values.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public sealed class Property : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        private readonly Type propertyType;
        private readonly bool isReadOnly;

        public Property(string name)
            : this(name, typeof(string))
        {
        }

        public Property(string name, Type propertyType)
            : this(name, propertyType, false)
        {
        }

        public Property(string name, Type propertyType, bool isReadOnly, params Attribute[] attributes)
            : base(name, attributes)
        {
            this.propertyType = propertyType;
            this.isReadOnly = isReadOnly;
        }

        public override Type ComponentType
        {
            get { return typeof(Record); }
        }

        public override Type PropertyType
        {
            get { return this.propertyType; }
        }

        public override bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return this.isReadOnly; }
        }

        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            var record = component as Record;
            return record != null ? record.GetValue(this.Name) : null;
        }

        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            var record = component as Record;
            if (record != null)
                record.SetValue(this.Name, value);
        }

        public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public sealed class RecordCollection : ObservableCollection<Record>, ITypedList
    {
        private readonly PropertyDescriptorCollection properties;

        public RecordCollection(params Property[] properties)
        {
            this.properties = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties);
        }

        PropertyDescriptorCollection ITypedList.GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            return this.properties;
        }

        string ITypedList.GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"/>
</Window>
```

The key thing in this code is **creating a Binding with a BindingPath that contains a Property instance, instead of a string**. This enables a simplification of PropertyDescriptor architecture because ICustomTypeDescriptor is not required anymore.

What do you think about this solution?

Comment: Thanks !! The idea is to use `MVVM` approach and change the cells dynamically based on type of data i.e. if its a collection, hook in a combobox cell, if a string then a TextBlock (readonly case) or a TextBox (if editable). I do not want to use the codebehind .cs file at all. Inspired on MVVM by this awesome video in this blog - `http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650`. So the link below which I have posted talks about `Data Templating (XAML)` based on the type of Data. `Can we do something similar with your logic in place ?`

Comment: DataGrid is a special control, it doesn't use implicit (based on DataType) or explicit DataTemplate when generating cell content. Cell content generation is based on a column to which cell belongs. DataGridColumn.GenerateElement (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.generateelement.aspx) is a method responsible for generating cell content and each DataGridColumn-derived class generates a different content. So I think that you won't be able to solve this without using codebehind. Note that codebehind should not be considered wrong in MVVM as many think.

Comment: It would be wrong only if your ViewModel code-behind would reference Views, which is clearly not the case in my presented solution. I am not sure anymore is your data column-homogeneous or column-heterogeneous (are all cells in a specific column of the same type?). If all cells in a specific column are of the same type, then you can easily extend my code with your requirements (you only need to handle creating of ComboBox cell, other requirements are already taken care of) by extending the code in MainWindow.OnAutoGeneratingColumn method.

Comment: In MainWindow.OnAutoGeneratingColumn method, just check if Property.PropertyType is a collection type, and if it is, set e.Column to new instance of DataGridComboBoxColumn and set ItemsSource and SelectedItemBinding on a DataGridComboBoxColumn.